# Select the most recent value, based on a different field in a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQLServer2008 and have run into a problem I have never seen before. I have a dataset, where some values are replicated multiple times for each quarter. I am trying to select the most recent value in each quarter.

```
SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
                        , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) AS Quarter
                        , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                    FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                    JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
                        ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
                    WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
                        AND (PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 22 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 795 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 796)

                    GROUP BY PPAV.BusinessID
                            , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1)))
                            , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
```

This is the code where the problem originated. I only want one value per quarter. Sometimes there is a change mid quarter, and information is duplicated. When I tried to remedy this, I was using this code, and it actually made the problem worse, by making the problem Quarter have 4 values.

```
SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
                        , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) AS Quarter
                        , CASE WHEN (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) = (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1))) 
                            THEN SubHist.PartnerAttributeValue
                            ELSE PAV.PartnerAttributeValue 
                            END AS PartnerAttributeValue
                FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
                    ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
                JOIN ( SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
                                    , MAX(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) AS MAX
                                    , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                                FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
                                JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
                                    ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
                                WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
                                AND (PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 22 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 795 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 796)
                                GROUP BY PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                                        ,PPAV.BusinessID
                        )SubHist
                    ON SubHist.BusinessID = PPAV.BusinessID
                WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
                    AND (PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 22 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 795 OR PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = 796)
                GROUP BY PPAV.BusinessID
                        , (cast(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(4)) + '0' + cast(datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate) as char(1)))
                        , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
                        , SubHist.PartnerAttributeValue
```

I am very unsure as to what I did to make the problem worse. I figured my CASE WHEN statement coming off the additional joined table would fix it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is some sample data that I am trying to eliminate

```
4356    201501  REGISTERED
4356    201502  REGISTERED
4356    201503  REGISTERED
4356    201504  REGISTERED
4356    201601  GOLD
4356    201601  REGISTERED
4356    201602  REGISTERED
4356    201603  REGISTERED
4356    201604  REGISTERED
```

The problem is where Q1 of 2016 has multiple values, the data gets skewed due to that. There should only be the GOLD value, not GOLD and Registered

Thank you!

Comment: you want one value per quarter, but may be more than one value in the quarter, I think you need to use aggregate function, SUM for example.

Comment: Seems like you could use a window function such as `row_number() over (partition by BusinessID, Quarter, order by PartnerAttributeValueStartDate desc) RN` wrap that in a subselct or cte and then add `Where RN = 1`

Comment: Im not sure a sum would work. This is just a small subset of a larger query. The value is a character value, so I need the character value for the max date when quarters are equal. This query is just one part of a larger CTE that uses the ROW_number trick, the performance of the larger function is already pretty poor :(

Comment: where is your date field saying the row with GOLD is later than the row with REGISTERED for the same ID and quarter?  Is it PartnerAttributeValueStartDate?

Comment: all you may need is to add a condition to your join- where you have `ON SubHist.BusinessID = PPAV.BusinessID` add `AND startDate = max`

Answer (score 2):

Use a window function to generate a row number for each quarter and business ID. Then limit to only the 1st row number (RN) of each group...

Since RN has to be generated before we can limit by it, we wrap it in a CTE or subquery and then apply RN=1...

I also:

1. Switched your OR statements to be an IN for readability and possibly performance.
2. Modified the quarter calculation to use concat instead of + string aggregation. (relying on implicit conversion which should be ok if processing valid date)

any of these additional changes may have introduced syntax errors as well.

**UNTESTED** If table structure for the below and sample data were provided in a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) I would test it.

```
Select * from (

    SELECT PPAV.BusinessID
         , concat(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate)
                  , '0'
                  ,datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate)
                 )
          AS Quarter
         , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue
         , row_number() 
           Over (PARTITION BY PPAV.BusinessID
               , year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate)
               , datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate))
                 ORDER BY PartnerAttributeValueStartDate DESC) RN
     FROM Partner_PartnerAttributeValue PPAV
     JOIN PartnerAttributeValue PAV
       ON PAV.PartnerAttributeValueID = PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID
     WHERE PAV.PartnerAttributeID = 7
       AND PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueID IN (22, 795,796)
     GROUP BY PPAV.BusinessID
           , concat(year(PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate)
                  , '0'
                  ,datepart(qq, PPAV.PartnerAttributeValueStartDate)
                 )
           , PAV.PartnerAttributeValue) cte

from cte where RN = 1
```

Comment: I'd probably just partition on the year and quarter parts without putting them back together. Is there an advantage to doing it that way? Same story with the `group by`, right?

Comment: No good point... and I should probably sort by the start date desc instead of allowing the default asc...

Comment: I dont think I can run a CTE within a sub-querey. I should have been more specific with the fact that this query is apart of a join from a much larger query

Comment: you can do it as a subquery... doesn't have to be a cte..  the rn trick isn't really much of a trick window functions operate VERY efficiently.